# Not to able make run apple tv app in real device

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I am facing problem when trying to run an Apple TV application on the real device. It is working perfectly when I run it in simulator but when I try to run the same code on the real device I receive the following error: "appTV[161:4731] Failed to load "

No idea why it is showing like this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you load an example AppleTV app and run that? Perhaps its your development license setup and not your code?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, it seems an issue of certificate than code. It works fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the latest Apple TV? It should work with the USB C cable. One way to test is to make a beta release and install it with TestFlight.